# C++ pure virtual function has no overrider

Tags: c++

I'm trying to recreate space invaders in it's most basic form. For my game i currently have a couple of classes, one for the game functionality, one for the game engine, and one for the player.

My current problem is that i have no overrider and no default constructor, Which i find very confusing, because in the "GameFunction.H" file on line 15 and 20 I put overrrides into the functions and it still wont work.

In the player class "Player.h" I created the constructor to initialize data for the player and provided parameters in the "Game.cpp" file on line 14.

I don't understand why it still won't work, am I missing something?

github link: https://github.com/JarodIking/Game-C-

(this is a visual studio project)

Heres the Game.cpp file

```
// Game.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "olcConsoleGameEngine.h"
#include "GameFunction.h"
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GameFunction game;
    Player player = new Player(100, 20, 60);
    game.ConstructConsole(160, 160, 8, 8);
    game.Start();


    return 0;
}
```

Heres the GameFunction.h file

```
#pragma once

class GameFunction : public olcConsoleGameEngine{
public:
    GameFunction() {

    }

private:

protected:
    bool OnUserCreate() override {
        return true;

    }

    bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) override {
        Fill(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), L' ');
        return true;
    }

};
```

And here's the Player.h file

```
#pragma once

class Player : public olcConsoleGameEngine {
public:
    //constructor
    Player(int health, int positionX, int positionY) {
        playerHealth = health;
        playerPositionX = positionX;
        playerPositionY = positionY;

    }


private:
    //private variables
    int playerHealth;
    int playerPositionX;
    int playerPositionY;

protected:
    int playerPosition(int X, int Y) {
        Fill(X, 5 * 6, Y, 5 * 6 + 10, PIXEL_SOLID, 5);

    }
};
```

By doing this I hope to keep track of the player position by saving the coordinates in separate variables inside the player class and color the pixels accordingly(not a simple as just X and Y of course).

I was also thinking of making a separate class for the bullets, 1 for the player and 1 for the aliens.

After that i want to make a class to create the 'cover' in space invaders, these will be the easiest

How do you guys recommend i go about the aliens themselves? I personally thought about creating a single class for the aliens and than use a loop to create multiple objects with it and thus have more aliens on screen. With a constructer to give each individual alien its own position, that way i can make them all move to same with perhaps a static function. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the error message? Please include it in the question

Comment: `Player` does not override `OnUserUpdate`, and there is at least one more pure virtual method in `olcConsoleGameEngine`: `virtual bool OnUserCreate()`. If a subclass does not provide a definition for those, the subclass is abstract and you cannot create instances

Comment: `Player player = new Player(100, 20, 60);` isn't right. You probably want `Player player(100, 20, 60);` instead.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want the Player object to inherit from the game engine?  I've never used olc, but it was my understanding that you only want one class providing the main game loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// User MUST OVERRIDE THESE!!
virtual bool OnUserCreate() = 0;
virtual bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) = 0;
```

These functions must be overriden in every class that extends olcConsoleGameEngine. At the moment you have only overriden them in GameFunction.

Also you are using the new keyword to create a player instance. This requires storage as a pointer not a plain variable. Possible alternatives are:

`Player* player = new Player(100, 20, 60) //create a pointer to a player`

or

`Player player(100, 20 60) //create standard player variable`

If you choose to create a pointer you'll need to also remember to delete it before the application closes.

`delete player`

Comment: `auto player = std::make_unique<Player>(100, 20, 60)` for smart pointer.